# Does Tomcat or Jetty support "java:comp/DefaultDataSource"

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, datasource, apache-tomee

Java EE 7 requires support for a default [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) as discussed:

- [Defaults in Java EE 7 (Tech Tip #37)](https://therichwebexperience.com/blog/arun_gupta/2014/07/defaults_in_java_ee_7_tech_tip_37_) by Arun Gupta
- [Using default DataSource to simplify the development and deployment of a Java EE application](https://vaadin.com/blog/using-default-datasource-to-simplify-the-development-and-deployment-of-a-java-ee-application) by Matti Tahvonen

While I realize [*Apache Tomcat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) & [*Eclipse Jetty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)) provide only a small subset of [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) features, I wonder if either provides a way to configure such a default `DataSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Jetty and Apache Tomcat are defined as "[web containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container)".

They only support the [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) spec and a few incidental/related specs around the Servlet spec (such as JSP, JAAS, JSR 356 javax.websockets, etc).

For Eclipse Jetty, there's no full Java EE support option.

For Apache Tomcat, there's [*TomEE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_TomEE) to bring in more of the features of Java EE to comply with the [*Web Profile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_profile) of Java EE.

As for `comp/DefaultDataSource`, neither project has a mention of it in their codebases (not even testcases or documentation).

- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DefaultDataSource&type=
- https://github.com/apache/tomcat85/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DefaultDataSource&type=